# What is the precise meaning of "f***" in the context of the hip hop mantra, "F*** bitches, get money"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, slang, offensive-language, lyrics

I've been hearing the line "Fuck bitches / Get money" in hip hop songs recently. I mostly noticed it lately in a couple of notable songs by Lil Wayne and other Young Money affiliated artists, but through some casual searching, the term seems to originate in pop culture from a Notorious B.I.G. song called "Get Money."

Until recently I assumed that the term was supposed to be a tongue-in-cheek *raison d'être* for hip hop figures; that is, to have sex with lots of women and to make a lot of money, in rock-star fashion.

But I sometimes see young people use the phrase as a hustler mantra, to disregard the pursuit of women/love for the pursuit of money/status/career.[1] The female counterpart would be "Fuck niggas / Get money."

Could I get some clarification on this, and possibly an explanation for how this latter meaning could be popularized when it (in my opinion) clashes with the hyper-masculine rock star image in mainstream hip hop culture? I know this phrase's precise meaning is in some dispute in pop culture.[2]

[1] http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/joseph-ducreux-archaic-rap

- see also: the Urban Dictionary entry for "fbgm"

[2] http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3qvlyk/

Comment: Given the popularity of the [bros before hoes](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bros%20before%20hoes) mantra, I suppose it's likely *most* people who say [Fuck bitches, get money](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fbgm) are using "fuck" to mean "don't **waste time** with", rather than "**have sex** with". But I'm sure both senses co-exist, and it's subjective/Not Constructive for ELU to adjudicate on a single "true" meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's quite an interesting interpretation, I never thought of it that way. To be honest I never bothered to think about it too deeply until seeing this question. Initially I would imagine that it's something that's meant to sound good and perhaps rhymes with certain other things in a useful way

Comment: @axrwkr: I'm guessing (wildly) that the way you never thought of was the *fuck = have sex with* interpretation. But of course, it could have been the other one. In any but the most vacuous written usages I'd have thought the intended meaning would be obvious from context. But it's worth pointing out that so far as I can tell, even with no context whatsoever the intonation should make it clear what sense is intended in spoken form (*"Don't do this, [instead] do that"* sounds completely different to *"Do this [and] do that"*). And real language is normally ***spoken***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It seems that the "bros before hoes" meaning is closer to the intended original meaning of the phrase. This is especially clear looking at the two most notable songs that use this phrase. In Notorious B.I.G.'s "Get Money", he is addressing a former lover who betrayed him ("Cause of you, I'm on some real fuck a bitch shit"). Also, Lil Wayne clarifies in "Money on My Mind" that he believes, "Money over bitches I'm yelling it to the grave".